# Subo archivos PDF por POST pero $_FILES type no los detecta como tal

Tags: php, html

Buenas, tengo un formulario en el que subo un archivo .PDF El problema es que en ocasiones, si detecta a los PDF y otras veces a otros archivos con esa misma terminación me indica que no son de ese tipo. ¿Qué podría hacer?
Les dejo aquí un extracto de mi código

```
<form action="upload_book_prueba.php" method="post" class="regisform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Subir el ebook </label>
<input type="file" name="ebook"   />
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
extract($_POST);
$ebook=$_FILES['ebook']['tmp_name'];
if($_FILES['ebook']['type']=="application/pdf") {                                           
$ruta_ebook="ebook/".$nombre_ebook.".pdf";
if(copy($ebook,$ruta_ebook)){
echo "Entra aqui";
}else{
echo "No entro";
}
}
}
```

NOTA: $nombre_ebook corresponde a una consulta del max id de la tabla ebooks, y le sume 1 a ese numero.

Comment: Es recomendable que uses [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php) en lugar de `copy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No uses `$_FILES['ebook']['type'] == "application/pdf"` por los siguientes dos motivos:

1. Depende del navegador enviar o no el tipo correcto (quizá mande otro genérico como `application/octet-stream`).
2. Al ser proporcionado desde el navegador del cliente (y no detectado en el servidor, donde tienes el control de cómo se hace la comprobación) puede ser fácilmente alterado por un usuario para fines maliciosos.

En su lugar deberías usar [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/mime-content-type) y permitir a tu servidor detectar el tipo analizando el contenido del archivo subido haciendo uso de los números mágicos (`magic.mime`) de tu servidor.

---

**Ejemplo con [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/mime-content-type):**

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post"
      class="regisform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>
    Subir el ebook (máximo <?=
      htmlspecialchars(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'))
    ?>)
  </label>
  <input type="file" name="ebook" />
  <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  extract($_POST);
  $ebook = $_FILES['ebook']['tmp_name'];
  if ($_FILES['ebook']['error'] !== 0) {
    echo 'Error al subir el archivo (¿demasiado grande?)';
  } else {
    if (
      mime_content_type($_FILES['ebook']['tmp_name']) == 'application/pdf'
    ) {
      $ruta_ebook = 'ebook/' . $nombre_ebook . '.pdf';
      if (move_uploaded_file($ebook, $ruta_ebook)) {
        echo "Entra aqui";
      } else {
        echo "No entro";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Ejemplo con [`finfo::file()`](http://php.net/function.finfo-file):**

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post"
      class="regisform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>
    Subir el ebook (máximo <?=
      htmlspecialchars(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'))
    ?>)
  </label>
  <input type="file" name="ebook" />
  <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  extract($_POST);
  $ebook = $_FILES['ebook']['tmp_name'];
  if ($_FILES['ebook']['error'] !== 0) {
    echo 'Error al subir el archivo (¿demasiado grande?)';
  } else {
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    if (
      strpos($finfo->file($_FILES['ebook']['tmp_name']),
        'application/pdf') === 0
    ) {
      $ruta_ebook = 'ebook/' . $nombre_ebook . '.pdf';
      if (move_uploaded_file($ebook, $ruta_ebook)) {
        echo "Entra aqui";
      } else {
        echo "No entro";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Aumentando el tamaño de archivos recibidos**

Lo ideal es modificar el archivo `php.ini` y configurar [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.upload-max-filesize) y [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.post-max-size) con un valor mayor.

Por ejemplo, para configurar 32 MiB usando [notación `shorthand`](http://php.net/faq.using#faq.using.shorthandbytes), deberemos poner:

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

Otra opción alternativa es crear un archivo `.htaccess` (si usas apache y está habilitado su uso) con el siguiente contenido:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 32M
```

Comment: Pero la pagina oficial de PHP la indica como una funcion obsoleta: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: Porque ahora se recomienda la interfaz ofrecida por [`Fileinfo`](http://php.net/ref.fileinfo) con la función [finfo_file() / finfo::file](http://php.net/finfo-file), pero por ahora sigue dando servicio (incluso en PHP 7.1), así que puedes usar cualquiera de las dos (te propuse esa porque era la que recordaba de memoria). Si necesitas un ejemplo de cómo usar la función (una u otra) dímelo y modifico tu código para hacer uso de esta funcionalidad, la idea de mi respuesta era explicarte la raíz del problema que planteas en tu pregunta.

Comment: Si puedes subir un ejemplo te lo agradecería, porque tengo unos minutos probando y me da error en la apertura del archivo

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta para ponerte dos ejemplos. Mucho ojo con `strpos()`, la comparación es estricta con `0` (coincidencia al comienzo) ya que el tipo mime puede contener, además, la codificación usada. Ejemplo: `application/pdf; charset=binary`.

Comment: Utilicé el mime_content_type() y ya el código no da error, la cosa es que sigue el problema de que algunos archivos que subo PDF me dice que no son PDF ¿por qué ocurre eso?

Comment: ¿Podrías subirme alguno que te provoca ese fallo a alguna pagina como Dropbox, Mega, Drive, etc o decirme la URL donde descargarlo?

Comment: Este es uno de los que me da error: 
https://mega.nz/#!IkRThKaS!syfOgR9i8dTBH7iNlsQmNbzPH1uibqWFBlvFSgjixjU
Me coloca: Warning: mime_content_type(): Empty filename or path in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\upload_file.php on line 212 Ademas de que esta condicional me da false: if (mime_content_type($_FILES['ebook']['tmp_name']) == 'application/pdf')

Comment: Todo apunta a que tu PHP está configurado con un límite de 2 MiB de tamaño máximo de archivos. Como no compruebas el valor de `$_FILES['ebook']['error']` no eres consciente de ello.

Comment: ¿Has podido comprobar lo que te comenté? ¿Has visto la edición que hice para que muestre el tamaño máximo y detecte problemas subiendo un archivo?

Comment: Estoy trabajando desde un servidor local con xampp, y trate de modificar y no lo conseguí.

Comment: ¿Qué probaste? ¿Modificar el `php.ini` o crear un `.htaccess`? ¿Qué tamaño máximo te aparece cuando cargas mi ejemplo? ¿2M?