# Ayuda PHP no reconoce type de pdf

Tags: php

$_FILES["archivo"]["type"] no trabaja con pdf, cualquier otro tipo como jpg o png o csv los reconoce type pdf aparece en blanco, estoy trabajando con php 5.6.31

cualquier otra solución para reconocer el type pdf seria de muy grande ayuda, gracias

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43232/subo-archivos-pdf-por-post-pero-files-type-no-los-detecta-como-tal Esta respuesta te puede servir

Comment: SOLUCION:
$sol = pathinfo($nombre_archivo);
if($sol['extension']=='pdf'){
 echo 'pdf';
}else{
 echo 'no-pdf';
}

Answer (score 1):

El tipo MIME de un PDF es `application/pdf`. Prueba lo siguiente:

```
$tipoArchivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["type"];
if (strpos($tipoArchivo, "/pdf") !== false) {
    // Es un pdf
} else {
    // No es pdf
}
```

Otra cosa de la que te tienes que asegurar es que el archivo esté llegando correctamente. Por ejemplo, puede tener un peso mayor que lo que permite tu configuración de PHP (en `php.ini`). Mira la directiva `post_max_size`, cuyo valor es de 8Mb (`8M`). Si hace falta, amplíala. También debes mirar el valor de la directiva `upload_max_filesize` (yo lo tengo en `20M`, pero creo que el valor por defecto es menor). Asegúrate de que ambas estén descomentadas (sin `;` delante).

La mejor forma de ver si el problema te viene por las directivas del servidor es, tras asegurarte de que tu pdf está correcto con un lector de pdf, como el acrobat reader, comprobar si hay algún número distinto de `0` en `$_FILES["archivo"]["error"]`.

A mí me pasó hace poco y era por esas dos directivas. Asegúrate de reiniciar Apache si las cambias.